# batch script to check if a process exists does not work if contain dot in the name

Tags: c#, shell, batch-file

```
@echo off

 tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe"  | 

find /i "Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe" >nul &&

 (
 echo Crashed is running
 ) ||
 (
echo Crashed is not running
 )

 pause>nul
```

The above code does not work. But works fine if we give process name as `imagename eq notepad.exe`.

Need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be the dots, but the filename length:

tasklist gives me Dummy.Platform.Crashing.e instead of Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe and

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe"  | find /i "Dummy.Platform.Crashing.e"
```

works fine.

Maybe replace /nh with /FO LIST:

```
tasklist /FO LIST /fi "imagename eq Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe"  | find /i "Dummy.Platform.Crashing.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks Klein, It was with the length,